# Toggle classes with getElementsByClassName inside a foreach loop with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementsbyclassname, nodelist

I am having trouble getting this toggle classes script working across all project divs.

It is set up so when the parent element is clicked, both child elements toggle the class `.hide`, which functions more as a swap.

Noting this similar post which uses Jquery [Toggle classes inside a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492261/toggle-classes-inside-a-foreach-loop), I have approached this differently because in this instance there are multiple classes to change.

I used `getElementsByClassName` and defined the element from the NodeList as `[0]`. This works for the first Project div and for the second when changed to `[1]`.

However, I am stuck on how I can get this working across all subsequent Project divs at the same time. Is this done with a loop? Or using variables? Or by using a `this` keyword?

I am using Kirby CMS to generate content sections so the Project divs are templated inside a `foreach` loop.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('read-more-div')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {

  document.getElementsByClassName('read-more-btn1')[0].classList.toggle('hide');
  document.getElementsByClassName('read-more-btn2')[0].classList.toggle('hide');

  return false

})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

p,
button {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.read-more-btn1 {
  color: #888888;
  cursor: s-resize;
}

.read-more-btn2 {
  cursor: n-resize;
}

.read-more-btn1:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>Project A

  <div class="read-more-div">

    <button class="read-more-btn1">Read more...</button>
    <p class="read-more-btn2 hide">Toggle this project text</p>

  </div>

</div>

<div>Project B

  <div class="read-more-div">

    <button class="read-more-btn1">Read more...</button>
    <p class="read-more-btn2 hide">Toggle this project text</p>

  </div>

</div>

<div>Project C

  <div class="read-more-div">

    <button class="read-more-btn1">Read more...</button>
    <p class="read-more-btn2 hide">Toggle this project text</p>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Comment: Something like `addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => { if(target.closest(".read-more-div")){ target.querySelectorAll(".read-more-btn1, .read-more-btn2").forEach(({ classList }) => classList.toggle("hide")); } });`.

Comment: Note that `return false;` can be removed. It doesn’t do anything.

Comment: Good to know as another approach! I'll have to read into event delegation which looks a little more complicated. I'm still in the early stages of learning js

Comment: The snippet doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why yet

Comment: Oops, you’re right. There’s another `.closest(".read-more-div")` missing between `target` and `.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: If [optional chaining](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is supported, there’s a shorter way: `addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => target.closest(".read-more-div")?.querySelectorAll(".read-more-btn1, .read-more-btn2")?.forEach(({ classList }) => classList.toggle("hide")));`.

Comment: Even better: instead of `hide`, use a class called `expanded` which gets placed on the `<div class="read-more-div">`; do `.read-more-div.expanded .read-more-btn1 { display: none; } .read-more-div.expanded .read-more-btn1 { display: block; }` and `addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => target.closest(".read-more-div")?.classList?.toggle("hide"));`. _Even_ better: use the standard [`<details>`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this. Ensure that you are adding event listeners to all the divs and not just the first one.
Looking at your current code you can follow this approach.

`this` inside event listener belongs to the element that triggered the event. So when we do `this.getElementsByClassName` we are querying for classes only inside that particular element.

`getElementsByClassName` does not return an array. It returns a collection which is **array-like**. To use `forEach()` on that array-like object converting it into an array is required. Using the `...` (spread) operator to convert the collection into an array.

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('read-more-div')].forEach(x => x.addEventListener('click', function() {

  this.getElementsByClassName('read-more-btn1')[0].classList.toggle('hide');
  this.getElementsByClassName('read-more-btn2')[0].classList.toggle('hide');

  return false

}));
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

p,
button {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.read-more-btn1 {
  color: #888888;
  cursor: s-resize;
}

.read-more-btn2 {
  cursor: n-resize;
}

.read-more-btn1:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>Project A

  <div class="read-more-div">

    <button class="read-more-btn1">Read more...</button>
    <p class="read-more-btn2 hide">Toggle this project text</p>

  </div>

</div>

<div>Project B

  <div class="read-more-div">

    <button class="read-more-btn1">Read more...</button>
    <p class="read-more-btn2 hide">Toggle this project text</p>

  </div>

</div>

<div>Project C

  <div class="read-more-div">

    <button class="read-more-btn1">Read more...</button>
    <p class="read-more-btn2 hide">Toggle this project text</p>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, and thanks for explaining.

Probably need to get my head around the theory but glad to know it wasn't too far off.

Any tips for debugging this sort of problem?